# split things apart

Tags: modeling

As you can see in the picture I was able to split the dividing bar and the camera foot attachment (right) from the main model. However some of the wires still on the main body.  The intention is to be able to resize the main body and the divider on the left without affecting the camera foot attachment (right) so I can re attached it later.  Basically I want to be able to stretch the main body on the x and y axis the re-attach the all the components.  The other issue is that if I stretch it with the other part it also stretch those.  Or can Just stretch the main body without affecting the size of the camera foot adapters (right). [image]

Comment: If the foot attachment is the object on its own on the right, hover the mouse over it and hit 'L' to select it. Then hit 'P' > Selection which will split it into a seperate object which will not be affected by scaling the other parts. If required you can join it back into one object later with CTRL-J.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)